# How to execute sql script before and after each test method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, junit

There is an `@Sql` annotation in spring which allows to execute *sql* code before and after the test method:

```
@Test
@Sql("init.sql")
@Sql(scripts = "clean.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public void someTest()
{
}
```

However I have several test methods where I would like to provide the same clean environment like in the test above and I don't want to repeat for every test the same `@Sql` annotation. How to do it once for all methods? For example:

```
// JPA and Spring other test annotations
@Sql("init.sql")
@Sql(scripts = "clean.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class TestClass
{
  // init.sql executed before every test, clean.sql executed after every test
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed when you place `@Sql` on the `class`, *sql* scripts will be executed before and after every test defined in that class, more specifically before `@Before` and after `@After` methods. So,

```
// JPA and Spring other test annotations
@Sql("init.sql")
@Sql(scripts = "clean.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class TestClass
{
  // init.sql executed before every test, clean.sql executed after every test
}
```

is going to work according to the `@Sql` definition:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
/// other annotations
public @interface Sql {
   //
}
```

Comment: Where should you plase the sql scripts in the above appraoch? Under test resuorce folder?

Comment: If I were to run above sql in IntegrationTest folder, what more changes have to do?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to execute an init script to put the DB in a certain state, and then ensure the DB is back to that state before each test method, right?

The simplest solution is to use `@Transactional`, then. By default, Spring Boot will automatically roll back the test transaction of a `@Transactional`-annotated test, thus resetting the DB to the original state.

There are two downsides one should consider, though:

1. `@Transactional` means there will exist a transaction spanning the entire execution of the test method which the tested service methods will typically join. Hence, the test itself cannot be relied upon to verify the correctess of transactional boundaries in the production code (`LazyInitializationException`s may be covered by this 'outer' transacion, for example)
2. The persistence context will not flush unless necessary, meaning that some issues (e.g. DB constraint violations) will not surface. I tend to work around that issue using a last-chance flush like so:

```
  @After
  public void flushContext() {
    if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
      entityManager.flush();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Answering the first question: yes this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I use ```@DataJpaTest```, so ```@Transactional``` is used anyway. The reason why I wanted to run init and clear scripts is because of sequences which cannot be rolled back, so in the init.sql and clean.sql I drop sequences and recreate them consequently to have completely clean state. Thanks for the first remark about ```@Transactional``` very good point.