# How can I use DDL script for H2 to generate tables when testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, h2

I made a project and created DDL script using postgreSQL to create tables and mapped it in every entity class.

now my problem is H2 is auto-generating tables base on entity classes when testing. I want the tables to be exactly similar to the tables from postgreSQL to avoid problems, because I made some fields like id be dependent on postgreSQL id generation (GenerationType.Identity).

Comment: How to you expect fields that depend on Postgresql id generation to work in H2? Or do you mean you just let the database generate the id? In any case your tests should not depend on the ids themselves. Besides that, DDL can be executed like other SQL so just use a ramp-up method to execute the statements and set up H2 (if I remember correctly there should even be JUnit annotations that allow you to specify .sql files to be exectured before a test).

Comment: @Thomas yes, that's my current problem, postgresql id generation and some constraints not present in entity class.

Comment: Well, if id generation and the constraints depend on functionality that only Postgres provides you'd have a hard time getting that into H2. If H2 supports it then look for how to execute SQL scripts before each test with the unit testing framework of your choice (if it is JUnit this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744812/how-to-execute-sql-script-before-and-after-each-test-method)

Comment: *"H2 is auto-generating tables"* – it surely isn't… it maybe Hibernate though. I'd recommend to use a database migration tool such as Flyway ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool)).

Comment: You could use liquibase to track you database schema and changes to it independently of a database. With liquibase you can generate your databaseChangeLog (representation of your database) from your existing postgres and then create your H2 from that.

Comment: You say that "...some constraints not present in entity class". If you want to go the route of creating your database schema from your spring entities, you can add those constraints to the entities (for example with the `@Table` annotation).