# Execute sql script before and after each integration test method

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to run some sql scripts before my Spring-boot integration tests,

I refered this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744812/how-to-execute-sql-script-before-and-after-each-test-method) and placed my sql script at the root level in resources folder (i.e. `src/integrationTest/resources`)

**Cucumber Test stepDef class** `src/integrationTest/java/steps/StepDefinitions.java`

```
@Sql(scripts = "clean-up.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
public class StepDefinitions {

..
```

**clean-up.sql**

```
delete from my_table where id in ('FOP678A090839984D04BA76E07DEB7C58BC', 'FOP678A090839984D04BA76E07DEB7C5811');
commit;
```

However nothing deleted from my PostgreSQL after running Spring-boot integration tests

Comment: You should put the `@Sql` annotation on the `@CucumberSpringContext` annotated class. Upgrade Cucumber if you don't have that annotation.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Yep, that works !!! and need to add classpath like `@Sql(scripts = "classpath:clean-up.sql"...` to add the file in integrationTest resources folder.